# jQuery remote validation with server generated error message

Tags: jquery

I am using the Validation jQuery plugin to do some validation.  I have a service which returns "true" and "false" right now and everything is great.

However, the error message I am using is "That name is already taken."

I want the error message to be `"That name is already <a href="/item?id=543"> taken</a>."` where that item id is something returned from the server.   But I can't figure out how to return anything from the server other than a single true or false and still have the validation work.

I know I can do "The name xxx is taken" using JQuery.Format("The name {0} is taken") but I really want to give a hyperlink to the existing item, and I don't want to have to change the item pages to accept a name instead of an id.

Comment: What happens when you return that string?  That *should* work already, any string is treated as an error message.

Comment: nothing happens.  Even if I set a break point in the success callback of the ajax call in the validation plugin the break point isn't hit.  It is hit when I return "true" or "false" but not "This is an error message"

Comment: Are you passing the string in quotes?

Comment: @Nick Craver, that's the answer...  I can't really accept a comment though :(

Comment: I'll convert it, in hopes it's useful to others :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The validation plugin handles this already, but the call type is `"json"`, so you need to make sure the string (error message) is passed in quotes, like this:

```
"Error Message"
```

The plugin will use this as the displayed error message, handy eh? :)

Comment: Wait, so he was doing something like `return this is my error msg;` instead of `return "this is my error msg";`? Or is there something more happening here that I'm not getting.