# JQuery Validate Plugin - RegEx email prefix, domaiin suffix, and duplicate check - in one go!

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the wonderful [Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plugin for JQuery, and so far, so good - I even have it passing the entered email address to check against a database to make sure duplicate emails can't be entered. To extend this, however, I want to also ensure that the email prefix (before the @ symbol) does contain at least one period (.) - this is to ensure the users are using their *firstname.lastname* email address, and not their *firstletterlastname* email address (and to prevent them from having two accounts using each format).

As stated before, the remote validation of the address itself works fine, but the problem is the response only comes back as a JSON true/false value - if I could validate it in my server-side script, then pass back a string value, there might be some way of displaying an error message for the field appropriate to the error(s) - e.g.: "your email must be firstname.lastname", "the email suffix must be company.com", and "that email address is already registered". I've been reading the JQuery docs on Validation, but nothing I've found allows me to pass **back** more than just true or false.

**I've ended up solving this thanks to Andrew's help, as well as this post: [jQuery remote validation with server generated error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579459/jquery-remote-validation-with-server-generated-error-message)
The key was ensuring that the strings were encapsulated in double quotes, whereas the true string being passed back wasn't, so it would evaluate correctly and not display an error message. Yay for JQuery and the awesome Validation plugin!**

Any ideas/pointers on how to implement this would be greatly appreciated, and considering I looked through all 700+ entries on JQuery Validation here at SO, perhaps it will benefit others as well. Thanks in advance!

Here's some code with what I'm doing:

```
$("#MemberInfo").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
           error.insertAfter(element);
       },
    rules: {
        Memberemail: {
            required: true,
            //minlength: 1,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: "checkReg.cfm",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },

    },
    messages: {
        Memberemail: {
            required: "Please enter a valid @company.com email address",
            minlength: "Please enter a vaild email address",
            remote: jQuery.format("{0} is already registered")  
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation for the `remote` option:

> The response is evaluated as JSON and
>   must be true for valid elements, and
>   can be any false, undefined or null
>   for invalid elements, using the
>   default message; **or a string, eg.
>   "That name is already taken, try
>   peter123 instead" to display as the
>   error message.**

So in your server-side code, if you return a string, it should be shown as the error message.

Comment: Unfortunately, you fell into the same trap myself (and others) have with how this documentation is written - if you look at my sample code, the remote: part in the messages: section of the code shows the value of the field (the {0}) in a string - not what comes back from the response. I've already tried making the response something else than true or false, and the script fails without error in those cases. You can only return true/false, not a string, but can put the value of the field in a string as the error message.

Comment: One update: by adding the dataType: text attribute to the remote: part of my rules: section, I now get back a string - but now the problem is how to display the proper message based on what comes back - even "true" shows up! Is there a way to put IF: statements in the remote, so depending on what the string returned is, show a different message (and no message if everything checks out)?

Comment: @Joyrex: Sounds like you're making some progress--I'll do some digging and see if I can come up with anything. Thanks for the update!

Comment: Andrew: Thanks for the help and support - I've made even more progress, where I set all my error messages on the server-side, and so what gets passed as a string in the response shows for all the different conditions. The only issue I'm having now is getting no error to show if nothing's wrong - for valid entries, I'm sending "true", but since I'm no longer sending it as JSON, it simply prints "true" and doesn't tell the Validator plugin not to display anything.

Comment: @Joyrex: Could you possibly send back a boolean `true` value and not the string "true" in cases where the value is valid? I'm not sure what your server side code looks like (and I'm not knowledgeable in PHP), but this might be the way to go.

Comment: @Andrew: The interaction server-side is ColdFusion, actually - I'll see if I can do a boolean "true" and see if it doesn't show "true" but rather it doesn't trigger the validation message display unless it's anything BUT the boolean true.

Comment: @Joyrex: Cool. Not sure why I thought it was PHP, especially with a `.cfm` extension :~

Comment: Update: it seems that the problem is still client-side - if I change the dataType to JSON, the "true" validates as true just fine, and even though the error message(s) I want to display come back as "false" responses, I can't figure out how to get the Validate script to recognize them as "false" and display the string output.

Comment: Update2: I solved it! Thanks to this posting [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579459/jquery-remote-validation-with-server-generated-error-message[/link], keeping the dataType set to JSON, and ensuring the error message was encapsulated in "" is what solved it (true is passed as simply true, without quotes, which the validator will then parse correctly).

Comment: @Joyrex: Awesome! Glad you figured it out.